# How to SCP Data to ownCloud?

Tags: 16.04, raspberrypi, owncloud-server

Motivation: `owncloud-client` fails periodically because of many reasons; I need `scp` during those events. 
In server, `ls -la` at `$HOME`

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 masi masi 4096 May 31 14:14 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 May 31 10:18 ..
-rw------- 1 masi masi 1099 May 31 12:20 .bash_history
-rw-r--r-- 1 masi masi  220 May 31 10:18 .bash_logout
-rw-r--r-- 1 masi masi 3512 May 31 10:18 .bashrc
-rw-r--r-- 1 masi masi  675 May 31 10:18 .profile
-rw------- 1 masi masi 2632 May 31 14:14 .viminfo
```

I can

- `ssh masi@192.168.1.101`

I cannot for some reason

- `scp $HOME/5GBdata/ masi@192.168.1.101:$HOME/`

Where to SCP files?

Server: Raspberry Pi 3b. 
Client: Ubuntu 16.04.

### Review of Ankit's answer

Client-side

```
masi@masi:~/Documents/Masi$ rsync -avz Directory -e ssh masi@192.168.1.107:/home/masi/
sending incremental file list
Directory/
Directory/common_mistakes.tex

sent 484 bytes  received 58 bytes  63.76 bytes/sec
total size is 4,143  speedup is 7.64
```

Server-side

```
masi@raspberrypi:~ $ ls Directory/
common_mistakes.tex
masi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo cp -r /home/masi/Directory /var/www/owncloud/data/masi/files/

masi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo -u www-data php /var/www/owncloud/occ files:scan masi 
Scanning file   /masi/
Scanning folder /masi/
... 
Scanning file   /masi/files/Directory
...
Scanning folder /masi/files/Directory
Scanning file   /masi/files/Hematology/._common_mistakes.tex
Scanning file   /masi/files/Hematology/common_mistakes.tex
...
Scanning folder /masi/cache
```

where you have to have a complete path to `occ`. 
It works!

Comment: You have 50GB of documents on your client, that you want to put into owncloud server?  You can upload with scp and then rescan on the server.  However, I have no idea if the path your putting the files too is part of owncloud.  It looks like a simply user home folder.

Comment: I suggest rsync over ssh or sshfs https://help.ubuntu.com/community/rsync and https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-copy-files-with-rsync-over-ssh and https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSHFS . otherwise, IMHO, your question is too broad as there are probably 20 other options. Please ask a specific question about a specific option.

Comment: Just install the owncloud desktop client, put the data in the synchronised directory, and wait.

Comment: It's whatever directory you choose when installing the owncloud desktop client, and whose contents are synchronised with the server's.

Comment: I think you should read this. https://doc.owncloud.org/desktop/2.1/ (This is my last comment here.)

Comment: Is this solved ?

Comment: @Masi : Your question is not very clear. Could you explain what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Prerequisites:

1. **Data directory on the Owncloud server**
   : Connect to server via ssh.If you have installed owncloud server to default location (`/var/www`), then go to the config file to find about the data directory location.

`nano /var/www/owncloud/config/config.php`

This file will tell you the location of the data directory (the place where all the files are stored.).
Like this; [image: Config.php file of owncloud]

Now the **Solution**:

**First**, you can transfer the folder to the server using rsync and ssh. Its most convenient and fast (since compression is included). 
For example, from the local computer on the terminal use,

`rsync -avz /path/to/local/50GBfolder -e ssh username@address:/home/user`

**Next**, connect to server using ssh and from there copy folder to the owncloud data directory. (Two step are needed since you need root permission to copy to owncloud data directory which is owned by `www-data` user.)

***Copy files this way;***

`sudo cp -r /home/user/50Gbfolder /path/to/data/$owncloud_username/files/`

- Inside the data directory, there is a folder for each owncloud user as `owncloud_username`, then under that there is a folder as `files`; hence mentioned above in the command.

**Lastly,** update owncloud database  by scanning to identify the new files.
This is done by prebuilt command. First, change directory to your owncloud installation directory. For default this is `\var\www\owncloud`.
so,

`cd \var\www\owncloud`

If you do `ls`, you will see an executable as `occ` under this folder. This `occ` is a php based program.

***To run `occ` for rescan,***

`sudo -u www-data php occ files:scan $user_name`

Full rescan may take some time. After the rescan, you will see the folder when logged in from a browser.

---

Explanation:

- `rsync -avz /path/to/local/50GBfolder -e ssh username@address:/home/user`

`-a` includes recursive, permissions, links, group etc and much more. Check man-page. `-v` verbose, `-z` compress and transfer.

- `sudo cp -r /home/user/50Gbfolder /path/to/data/$owncloud_username/files/`

`-r` recursive folder copy, all subfolders are copied.

Comment: @Masi:  First question:  The path maybe different for your installation.  The one I have mentioned is for default installation.  Second question: For rsync  `-a` includes `-rlptgoD` which is for recursive, links, preserve permission, preserve modification times, preserve group, preserve ownership, preserve device files. It is much more than `-c`.   [ManPage for rsync](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync)

Comment: Thank you for the great explanation! I think I should be using `rsync -avz`.

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems with your scp command:

- You are trying to upload a directory, hence you must provide the `-r` option (copy recursively).
- The environment variables are substituted **before** the execution of the command. Therefore, `$HOME` in `masi@192.168.1.101:$HOME/` expands to the path of your home directory on your local (rather than the remote) machine. If the home directory paths on the two machines are different then the command will work not as you intended, most probably failing because of access problems. When using `scp`, refer to your home directory on the remote machine with '.' (in other words `scp` interprets paths on the remote machine relative to your home directory).

So the correct command will be:

```
scp -r $HOME/5GBdata/ masi@192.168.1.101:.
```

However, note that this answer only points out your mistakes in using `scp`. Refer to the other answer(s) for recommendations on how to achieve your final goal.